# Sub list of a list in taking the second element

Tags: list, tuples, ocaml

Suppose I have the following list of tuple `[("a", "b"); ("c", "d"); ("e", "f"); ("g", "h"); ("i", "j")]`. I would like to create a sub list from that list by taking the second element of each tuple of that list. In other words, I want to obtain `["a"; "d"; "f", "h"]`.

I tried `iter (fun (x,y) -> liste@[y]) old_list;;` but I got

```
Error: This expression has type (string * string) list
       but an expression was expected of type unit
```

Do I have to use a recursive function? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `List.iter` is `('a -> unit) -> 'a list -> unit`. In other words, it returns unit, which is the way in OCaml to return nothing (or nothing interesting anyway).

Since you want your function to return a result, you can't use `List.iter`. Instead, you want to transform each element of a list in some way. The function that does this is `List.map`.

Here's a function that changes a list of ints into a list of bools according to whether each int is odd or even:

```
let is_even list = List.map (fun x -> x mod 2 = 0) list
```

It works like this:

```
# is_even [3;4;5;6;7];;
- : bool list = [false; true; false; true; false]
```

You want something like this with a different `fun` expression.

As a side comment, your result isn't what would usually be called a sublist of the original list. A sublist is a new list containing some of the elements of the old list. You could call it a projection more accurately I think.